# Ordenar array de objetos por 2 atributos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quisiera ordenar un array de objetos por dos atributos.

El array es el siguiente:

```
var unidades = [{"id": 1, "numero": 3, "bloque": "F"},
                {"id": 2, "numero": 101, "bloque": "A"},
                {"id": 1, "numero": 1, "bloque": "F"},
                {"id": 1, "numero": 5, "bloque": "C"},
                {"id": 1, "numero": 1, "bloque": "A"}

];
```

Quiero ordenar el array primero por bloque y después por número, de forma ascendentes. Cómo puedo hacerlo ?
Ahora tengo una función que solo me ordena por bloque, pero me falta por el número, que es la siguiente:

```
function ordenarBloque(a,b) {
            if (a.bloque < b.bloque)
                return -1;
            else if (a.bloque > b.bloque)
                return 1;
            else 
                return 0;
        };
```

Alguna sugerencia ?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es cuestión de que agregues la segunda comparación cuando el primer campo es igual:

```
function ordenarBloque(a,b) {
        if (a.bloque < b.bloque)
            return -1;
        else if (a.bloque > b.bloque)
            return 1;
        else 
            if (a.numero< b.numero)
                return -1;
            else if (a.numero> b.numero)
                return 1;
            else 
                return 0;
    };
```